# How to get the original source and line number in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

I have the following code modified from Hello.cpp from LLVM source tree. The code currently prints the functions, the instructions, and the operands.

I also want to print the source filename and the lineno of the functions, the instructions, and the variables accessed. Could anybody show me how to do it?

```
$ cat Hello.cpp
/* vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2: */
#include "llvm/ADT/Statistic.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/InstIterator.h"
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
using namespace llvm;

#define DEBUG_TYPE "hello"

STATISTIC(HelloCounter, "Counts number of functions greeted");

namespace {
  // Hello - The first implementation, without getAnalysisUsage.
  struct Hello : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification, replacement for typeid
    Hello() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
      ++HelloCounter;
      errs() << "Hello: ";
      errs().write_escaped(F.getName()) << '\n';

      for (inst_iterator I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I) {
        errs() << "I:" << *I << "\n";
        for (Use &U : I->operands()) {
          Value *v = U.get();
          errs() << "v:" << *v << "\n";
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
}

char Hello::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<Hello> X("hello", "Hello World Pass");

$ ./main.sh ;./opt.sh 
Hello: main
I:  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
v:i32 1
I:  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
v:i32 0
v:  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
I:  call void (...) bitcast (void ()* @f to void (...)*)()
v:void (...)* bitcast (void ()* @f to void (...)*)
I:  ret i32 0
v:i32 0
Hello: f
I:  %1 = load i32, i32* @U, align 4
v:@U = common dso_local global i32 0, align 4
I:  %2 = add nsw i32 %1, 1
v:  %1 = load i32, i32* @U, align 4
v:i32 1
I:  store i32 %2, i32* @U, align 4
v:  %2 = add nsw i32 %1, 1
v:@U = common dso_local global i32 0, align 4
I:  ret void


==> main.sh <==
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

compile=(
    c++
    -I"$HOME"/opt/llvm/include
    -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic
    -g -fPIC
    -fno-rtti
    -o Hello.cpp.o -c Hello.cpp
)
"${compile[@]}"
link=(
    c++
    -Wl,-flat_namespace -Wl,-undefined -Wl,suppress
    -o x.so
    Hello.cpp.o
)
"${link[@]}"

==> opt.sh <==
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

cmd=(
    ~/opt/llvm/bin/opt
    -load x.so
    -hello
)
"${cmd[@]}" < hello.bc > /dev/null

==> hello.c <==
/* vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2: */
#include <stdio.h>

int U;

void f();

int main() {
  f();
  return 0;
}

==> f.c <==
/* vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2: */
#include <stdio.h>

extern int U;

void f() {
    ++U;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is only possible if source files were compiled with debugging info enabled.

Comment: That info looks like a lot of lines like `!39186 = !DILocation(line: 481, scope: !39143)` at the end of the file (and some other DIfoobar), and some markers like `!dbg !39186` on some IR instructions. You need to start with [getDebugLoc()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#ab4f3bf98b5054831b608852e33427814).

Answer (score 6):

You need to cast the values into `Instruction`, then you can access debug info through the `DebugLoc` class:

```
Value *v = U.get();
Instruction *instruction = dyn_cast<Instruction>(v);
const llvm::DebugLoc &debugInfo = instruction->getDebugLoc();

std::string directory = debugInfo->getDirectory();
std::string filePath = debugInfo->getFilename();
int line = debugInfo->getLine();
int column = debugInfo->getColumn();
```

**UPD:** Make sure you include required header files:

```
#include <llvm/IR/DebugLoc.h>
#include <llvm/IR/DebugInfoMetadata.h>
```

Comment: I got the following error. Do you know what is wrong? `Hello.cpp:32:39: error: member access into incomplete type 'llvm::DILocation'
                                        std::string directory = debugInfo->getDirectory();
                                                                         ^
/Users/pengy/opt/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Metadata.def:83:42: note: forward declaration of 'llvm::DILocation'`

Comment: @user1424739 you need to include headers files containing definitions of these classes: I'll update the answer.

Comment: I got segmentation fault. Could you help try the code and see what is wrong? `I:  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
Stack dump:
....14 opt                      0x000000010f41d201 llvm::legacy::PassManager::run(llvm::Module&) + 33
15 opt                      0x000000010c80c234 main + 28116
16 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff569f0015 start + 1
./opt.sh: line 12: 80208 Segmentation fault: 11  "${cmd[@]}"...`

Comment: It's likely that an instruction does not have the debug info. The call `debugInfo->getDirectory()` is equivalent to `debugInfo.get()->getDirectory()`, where the `get()` returns a pointer to `DILocation`, which is probably a null pointer in this case. Add more error handling.

Comment: Not sure how to do it. I try this. But it still produce the segmentation fault. Could you try the program and see what is wrong? Thanks. `auto di = debugInfo.get();          if(di == NULL) {
            errs() << "NULL" << "\n";
          } else {
            std::string directory = di->getDirectory();
            std::string filePath = di->getFilename();
            int line = di->getLine();
            int column = di->getColumn();

            errs() << "v:" << "\t" << *v << "\n";
            ...
          }   `

Comment: @AlexDenisov i am getting following error opt-7: test3.ll:68:209: error: invalid field 'nameTableKind' when i run the my pass .can you please help me on this? i want to get the line number of my function call, i am using following command clang -O0 -g -S -emit-llvm test3.c -o test3.ll

Comment: This this the correct answer if you add `-g` to the command line.